# Why is the "this.personService" is null only when the sub() method is called from other class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working a Java Spring MVC project.

In one of the controller classes

PersonController.java

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({ "mob_Number"})
public class PersonController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    public PersonController(PersonService personService){
        this.personService = personService;
    }


    public PersonController(){

    }

    ....

      @RequestMapping(value="/sub",method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sub(@RequestBody String json){


         List result = this.personService.getNumber();

     ....
}
```

The above this.personService is not null when I access the sub method from browser.

But in another class, I call the sub method as follows

PersonServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService, UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonServiceImpl.class);


    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    private PersonService personService;

    public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

      PersonController personController = new PersonController(personService);

      String res = personController.sub(codeJSON.toString());

....

}
```

If done via above method, the "this.personService" returns null.

1) Why is this happening?
2) How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Just as a note, if an injected property is *required*, you should use constructor injection instead of setter injection (move the `@Autowired` to the constructor).

Comment: Where is `PersonServiceImpl` getting its `personService`? It looks like perhaps you should be using `this` instead.

Comment: new PersonController(personService); <- personService is null at this point. Also you're creating a new instance of the controller instead of recovering it from the framework with the injected dependences.

Comment: @user3705478 In the `PersonServiceImpl` class, I think you wanted to use   `new PersonController(this);` instead of `new PersonController(personService);`.

Comment: @RubioRic Could you provide some more directions like how to do that?

Comment: @user3705478 Master Slave has given you a good answer. You're not structuring your application's layers correctly. You should not access the Controller from the Service. Please, take a look at this example on how to build a MVC Hello World. http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 2):

1) You're instantiating the `PersonController` bean instead of letting Spring inject it for you (altough you should never access controller from the service)

2) You should migrate the logic from the `sub` method to a method inside the the `PersonService`, and call this method from the `sub` method in Controller, also, directly from the service

Some further details,

Your PersonService is a spring bean, meaning that whenever you want to use it, you should let the framework inject it via e.g. `@Autowire`, otherwise it will be null.

A service layer should be referencing other service or DAO beans, its weird that you're using `PersonService` inside the `PersonServiceImpl`

Comment: Not the problem this time, at least not directly.

Comment: its definitely a problem, only not the only one, will edit my answer a bit

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem at all if `personService` were initalized at that point.

Comment: yes, but in all cases its better to create the method in `PersonService` and call it directly. He can make it work by instantiating the `PersonController` but that has nothing to do with spring. Its just hacking away